# accented characters displayed as “?”

Tags: java, spring

i have an xml which contains some special words bt after reading from db its converting those special characters to ? mark

input  xml one of the tag  :  <title_block_short>UNITED STATES v. GARCÍA NÚÑEZ</title_block_short>
<title_meta>UNITED STATES v. GARCÍA NÚÑEZ</title_meta>

```
current oupput : <title_block_short>UNITED STATES v. GARC��A N����EZ</title_block_short>
        <title_meta>UNITED STATES v. GARC��A N����EZ</title_meta>   


 desired output: <title_block_short>UNITED STATES v. GARCÍA NÚÑEZ</title_block_short>
           <title_meta>UNITED STATES v. GARCÍA NÚÑEZ</title_meta>
```

Sample code of reading xml in my application

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Document doc = xmlHelperTools.xmlStreamToDocument(is);
```

I have tried all the possible solutions,Could someone help me on this thanks for advance.

current oupput : <title_block_short>UNITED STATES v. GARC��A N����EZ</title_block_short>
<title_meta>UNITED STATES v. GARC��A N����EZ</title_meta>

Comment: *= new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));* How do you know it's UTF-8? Looks like it isn't. It might be, say, Windows-1252, but you shouldn't probably have to guess